# how to check contains in arraylist or set

Tags: java

I have two Strings

```
String first = "value=[ABC,PQR,XYZ]"
String second="value=[ABC]"
```

I am trying to check the contains of string second into a string first.
I am using the below code

```
List<String> list = new Arraylist<>();
list.add(first);
if(list.contains(second)){
    // do something
}
```

How to check contains in the list which has string with multiple ","?

Which data structure should I use for above problem?

Comment: Do you want to check if `ABC` is in `[ABC,PQR,XYZ]`? Or `[ABC]` is in `[ABC,PQR,XYZ]`? Or `value=[ABC]` is in `[ABC,PQR,XYZ]`? Or `value=[ABC]` is in `value=[ABC,PQR,XYZ]`?

Comment: `list.contains(...)` is looking for a string that's **equal**, and the only string in the list is not equal, so of course it returns false.

Comment: what is expected result for the inputs you have mentioned, should it print true or false

Comment: Your code does already what you are asking. If you want to check if `ABC` is contained in a list/set of `ABC`, `PQR`, `XYZ`, you can parse both strings first into a list/set that contains these entries.

Comment: want to check ABC is in [ABC,PQR,XYZ]

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you don't know how to work with lists in java...

In your case, you are adding a string **"value=[ABC,PQR,XYZ]"** to the list. Hence, you have a list with only one item.

If you want to create such a list **["ABC","PQR","XYZ"]**, you have to add these three elements one by one.

P.S. If you studied java basic, you wouldn't have such problems...

Comment: value=[ABC,PQR,XYZ]  getting me at runtime and value=[ABC] also at runtime.

Comment: You wrote you would like to check whether ABC is in [ABC,PQR,XYZ] or not. So, you need to check string "ABC" in the list ["ABC","PQR","XYZ"]. You don't need the word ***value***.

Answer (score 1):

```
String first = "value=[ABC,PQR,XYZ]";
String second ="value=[ABC]";
String secondVal = second.substring(second.indexOf("[") + 1, second.indexOf("]"));
String[] firstArry = first.substring(first.indexOf("[") + 1, first.indexOf("]")).split(",");
boolean secondInFirst = false; 
    
for (int i = 0; i < firstArry.length; i++) {
  if (firstArry[i].equals(secondVal)) {
    secondInFirst = true;
    break;
   }
}
```

I'm not sure why the first and second are formatted in such a way, however, assuming they are always formatted the same way ("value=[X,Y,Z]"),

- We must break first up into a fixed list ("value=[ABC,PQR,XYZ]" -> {"ABC","PQR","XYZ"})
- Format second to be readable ("value=[ABC]" -> "ABC")
- Loop through firstArry and find matches
- Store the result in secondInFirst